# Can't fit data to given function with scipy on python (Jupyterlab)

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, jupyter-lab

The problem is that I need to fit some data into a function (which was given by my professor, so basically I can't change it) but the fit goes poorly and I can't understand why. I also tried with lmfit method but that didn't work too. Here is the code I used and the image of the fit I get with residuals:[Fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGszU.png)

```
x1 = np.array([200.  , 220.  , 240.  , 260.  , 280.  , 300.  , 320.  , 340.  ,
       360.  , 380.  , 390.  , 392.5 , 395.  , 397.5 , 400.  , 402.5 ,
       405.  , 407.5 , 410.  , 411.25, 412.5 , 413.75, 414.  , 415.25,
       416.5 , 417.75, 418.5 , 420.  , 422.5 , 425.  , 427.5 , 430.  ,
       432.5 , 435.  , 437.5 , 440.  , 450.  , 460.  , 480.  , 500.  ,
       510.  , 520.  , 540.  , 560.  , 570.  , 580.  , 600.  ])

y1 = np.array([0.00787402, 0.00904762, 0.01079365, 0.01269841, 0.01539683,
       0.01857143, 0.02321429, 0.0302    , 0.04303279, 0.06767896,
       0.09456265, 0.10338983, 0.11410579, 0.12545932, 0.14700855,
       0.16944444, 0.19692833, 0.22965779, 0.27434783, 0.28681818,
       0.32079208, 0.32562814, 0.32893401, 0.33061224, 0.32727273,
       0.31268293, 0.30236967, 0.28940092, 0.24274194, 0.20989011,
       0.18052805, 0.15531915, 0.13259053, 0.11627907, 0.10341463,
       0.07345133, 0.07455357, 0.06403509, 0.04163265, 0.03811475,
       0.02948207, 0.0272    , 0.02301587, 0.02027559, 0.01968254,
       0.01795276, 0.01672584])

σ_y1 = np.array([0.00021564, 0.00023222, 0.00025707, 0.00028599, 0.00032924,
       0.00038243, 0.00046297, 0.00058876, 0.0008021 , 0.00127062,
       0.00180749, 0.00196919, 0.00217276, 0.00239208, 0.00284333,
       0.00317296, 0.00368032, 0.00432658, 0.00507593, 0.00532676,
       0.0060111 , 0.00611128, 0.00618   , 0.00621495, 0.00607953,
       0.0057964 , 0.0056074 , 0.00536185, 0.00463023, 0.00401191,
       0.00347255, 0.00303842, 0.00250275, 0.00219007, 0.00196289,
       0.0014738 , 0.00139797, 0.00129955, 0.00077378, 0.00082702,
       0.00054713, 0.00053481, 0.00043752, 0.00041071, 0.0003831 ,
       0.00037095, 0.00033556])

# Primo test di fit con 4 parametri
def fitfunc1(x, A, R, L, C, Off): # le frequenze 'f' sono in kHz
    ω = 2*np.pi*x 
    δ = R/(2*L)
    Ω = 1/sqrt(L*C)
    return A*ω/sqrt(ω**4-2*ω**2*(Ω**2-2*δ**2)+Ω**4)

R_tot = 77.54
R_G = 48
L = 308*1E-6
C = 508*1E-9

p_init1 = [31454, R_tot-R_G, L, C] # valori iniziali di (A, R, L, C)

p_best1, cov1 = curve_fit(
    fitfunc1, x1, y1,          # assegno funzione di fit, ascisse e ordinate
    sigma=σ_y1,                     # assegno gli errori sulle ordinate
    p0=p_init1, bounds=(0, +np.inf)  # imposto i valori iniziali dei parametri e intervalli ammessi [0, +∞) 
)                                 

#Somma dei residui e deviazione standard a posteriori
res1 = (y1-fitfunc1(x1, *p_best1))
sum_res1 = sum(res1)
σ_post1 = ma.sqrt(sum_res1/(y1.size))

print("---------------------------")
print("Best fit values:")
print("---------------------------")
print("A = (%.5f +/- %.5f)   err_percentuale = %.5f" % (p_best1[0],sqrt(cov1[0,0]),sqrt(cov1[0,0])*100/p_best1[0]))
print("R = (%.5f +/- %.5f) Ω err_percentuale = %.5f" % (p_best1[1],sqrt(cov1[1,1]),sqrt(cov1[1,1])*100/p_best1[1]))
print("L = (%.5f +/- %.5f) μH err_percentuale = %.5f" % (p_best1[2]*1E+6,sqrt(cov1[2,2])*1E+6,sqrt(cov1[2,2])*100/p_best1[2]))
print("C = (%.5f +/- %.5f) F err_percentuale = %.5f" % (p_best1[3]*1E+12,sqrt(cov1[3,3])*1E+12,sqrt(cov1[3,3])*100/p_best1[3]))
print("---------------------------")


fig1 = plt.figure(1, figsize=(9,7))
frame1a=fig1.add_axes((.1,.3,.7,.5))

# Grafico del fit
plt.errorbar(x1, y1, yerr=σ_y1, fmt='.', label='dati', capsize = 4)
_pts = np.linspace(x1[0], x1[-1], 1000)
plt.plot(_pts, fitfunc1(_pts, *p_best1), label='fit')
plt.title("Amplificazione ai capi di R")
plt.xlabel("frequenza [kHz]")
plt.ylabel(r"A = $V_{out}/V_{in}$")
plt.legend()
plt.tick_params(bottom = False)
plt.grid()
frame1a.set_xticklabels([])

# Grafico dei residui
frame1b=fig1.add_axes((.1,.1,.7,.19))
plt.errorbar(x1, res1, yerr = σ_y1, fmt ='.', capsize = 4)
plt.xlabel("frequenza [kHz]")
plt.ylabel(r"$A_{mis}-A_{fit}$")
plt.grid()

#salvataggio della file nella cartella, dpi = risoluzione immagine, bbox_inches = risolve problema di dimensione
#plt.savefig("name_of_file", dpi = 200, bbox_inches = "tight")
```

I tried several things like removing the bounds for the parameters but that gives me enormous errors, renaming the parameters (in case they conflicted with the name of the initial value) and varying the initial values to let the fit be more precise (however initial parameters should be fixed as I wrote them because those are values that were measured with particular devices). (R_tot-R_G) represents the resistance of our RLC circuit, L is the inductance, and C is the capacity. The only unknown value is the amplitude A of the curve. Thank you in advance!

Comment: They are only three independent parameters in the equation to be fitted : ( A, Omega, delta ). Not four parameters. This ambiguity is generally a major cause of non convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your script is a very good start, but there are two separate issues with your fit.  First, I think that you will find that for a single oscillator (and, just your mathematical function) that R, L, and C will not be able to be all determined independently -- they are almost completely correlated.  Fixing one of these values will allow the other two to be determined well.

Second, the initial values you used for R, L, and C are so far from optimal that the fit simply cannot find a better solution.  I think the simplest way to view that is that your initial value of L is too low by a factor of 1000.

Initial values always matter for a fit.  A related topic (or perhaps a third topic) is that you should put lower bounds of 0 on all of R, L, and C -- that's physically justifiable but also avoids problems with taking the square root of a negative number.

Using lmfit (as I am a lead author -- I'm sure this could be done with `curve_fit` and give nearly identical results), a fit allowing all of R, L, and C, as well as A and Off (added to your function) would look like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import lmfit

def fitfunc1(x, A, R, L, C, Off): # le frequenze 'f' sono in kHz
    ω = 2*np.pi*x
    δ = R/(2*L)
    Ω = 1/np.sqrt(L*C)
    return Off + A*ω/np.sqrt(ω**4-2*ω**2*(Ω**2 - 2*δ**2)+Ω**4)


model = lmfit.Model(fitfunc1)

params = model.make_params(A=40, R=30, L=0.30, C=0.5e-6, Off=0)
params['A'].min = 0
params['R'].min = 0
params['L'].min = 0
params['C'].min = 0
# params['L'].vary = False

init = model.eval(params, x=x1)

result = model.fit(y1, params, x=x1, weights=1/σ_y1)

print(result.fit_report())

# #Somma dei residui e deviazione standard a posteriori
res1 = y1 - result.best_fit

fig1 = plt.figure(1, figsize=(9,7))
frame1a=fig1.add_axes((.1,.3,.7,.5))
#
# Grafico del fit
plt.errorbar(x1, y1, yerr=σ_y1, fmt='.', label='dati', capsize = 4)
plt.plot(x1, result.best_fit, 'o', label='best fit')
_pts = np.linspace(x1[0], x1[-1], 1000)
plt.plot(_pts, result.eval(x=_pts), label='interpolated fit')
plt.title("Amplificazione ai capi di R")
plt.xlabel("frequenza [kHz]")
plt.ylabel(r"A = $V_{out}/V_{in}$")
plt.legend()
plt.tick_params(bottom = False)
plt.grid(color='#EEE')
frame1a.set_xticklabels([])
#
# ....
```

would give a fit report of

```
[[Model]]
    Model(fitfunc1)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 65
    # data points      = 47
    # variables        = 5
    chi-square         = 400.284733
    reduced chi-square = 9.53058888
    Akaike info crit   = 110.675341
    Bayesian info crit = 119.926079
    R-squared          = -673.477539
[[Variables]]
    A:    30.9354753 +/- 0.67812562 (2.19%) (init = 40)
    R:    23.3162313 +/- 1003.45159 (4303.66%) (init = 30)
    L:    0.25082189 +/- 10.7859228 (4300.23%) (init = 0.3)
    C:    5.8633e-07 +/- 2.5214e-05 (4300.36%) (init = 5e-07)
    Off:  6.8886e-04 +/- 4.3907e-04 (63.74%) (init = 0)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(L, C)   = -1.0000
    C(R, L)   = +1.0000
    C(R, C)   = -1.0000
    C(A, Off) = -0.8021
    C(A, R)   = +0.5709
```

showing huge uncertainties for R, L, and C because their correlations all exceed 0.999.

Simply fixing `L` (by uncommenting `# params['L'].vary = False`) would give a fit with the same value for `chi-square` and a report of

```
[[Model]]
    Model(fitfunc1)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 26
    # data points      = 47
    # variables        = 4
    chi-square         = 400.284733
    reduced chi-square = 9.30894728
    Akaike info crit   = 108.675341
    Bayesian info crit = 116.075931
    R-squared          = -673.477539
[[Variables]]
    A:    30.9354748 +/- 0.55046897 (1.78%) (init = 40)
    R:    27.8877948 +/- 0.84442502 (3.03%) (init = 30)
    L:    0.3 (fixed)
    C:    4.9022e-07 +/- 5.3035e-10 (0.11%) (init = 5e-07)
    Off:  6.8887e-04 +/- 3.9717e-04 (57.66%) (init = 0)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(A, R)   = +0.7666
    C(A, Off) = -0.7613
    C(R, Off) = -0.5502
```

FWIW, the plot using the above modifications of your code would look like

[image]

Comment: Good answer. Fixing one of the parameters was a key to overcome the difficulty. +1 .

Comment: Thanks! In the end i used the new parametric model with delta and Omega. Basically our professor wanted us to realize that using RLC as parameters is not the best way to do the fit. I realized you implemented data y errors by using weight= (1/sigma of y); so in order to take into account the errors I have to put sigmas on the denominator of weight?

Comment: Glad to hear that part of the point was to realize that (`delta`, `Omega`) was a better parametrization than (`R`, `L`, `C`) and I hope this helps illustrate that.  For accounting for errors: yes, `lmfit.Model` minimizes `(data-model)*weights`.  Very often, you want to minimize `(data-model)/uncertainties`, so you would want to do `weight=1/sigma_y`.  One reason we do that is to make it clear that any "divide by zero" error would show as being in the users own code, not buried somewhere deep in the library call.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method to get very good approximates of the parameters :

[image]

Now if you want more accurate results according to some criteria of fitting (LMSE, LMSRE, LMAE or other) you can use the above approximates values of parameters as initial values to start an iterative method of non-linear regression (with python or any other convenient software).

Comment: Yes, this is a lovely way to get initial values.  Trying to work out if (or to what extent) a fitting problem can be linearized is a very good thing to do.